# Implementing OAuth in asp.net error with context.RunClaimsAction(user)

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement oauth in asp.net 3.0, and I understand there were some changes as regards to changes to the Newtonsoft.Json types replaced in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication APIs link [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/341#issue-407002748)

It does not accept a JObject of the user's claims and throws an error when you try to pass a JObject as a parameter to the RunClaimActions(user) and does not throw an error when you run the method without passing the user JObject parameter in the method. The result is that it does not return the User claims to the view. Has anyone faced this problem yet ? Is there a way to convert a newtonsoft JObject to a JsonElement.

```
options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:login", "login");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:url", "html_url");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:avatar", "avatar_url");

                options.Events = new OAuthEvents
                {
                    OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                    {
                        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                        var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                        var user = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                        context.RunClaimActions(user);



                    }


                };
            });
```

Answer (score 14):

After some reading, I solved the issue by using the JsonDocument for parsing the claims and passing the root document to the RunClaimActions method.

```
    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
                {
                    OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                    {
                        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                        var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                        var user = JsonDocument.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());                                              
                        context.RunClaimActions(user.RootElement);



                    }
```